# as3 space bar function not workingf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I have written a code to move a `MovieClip` on pressing space bar. So if someone presses space bar ..it activates a boolean variable from `false` to `true` and if its true the object moves ..but its not working. can some one please help. Thank you

```
     var rope = MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.fishyrope_mc.hitbox_mc;
var ropeMove:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ropeCode);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onSpacebarUp);

function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
        ropeMove = !ropeMove; // toggles ropeMove (i.e. if it's true, sets it to false, and vice versa)
}

function ropeCode(e:Event):void
{
    // move the rope
    if( ropeMove )
    {
        rope.y += xSpeed;

        // stop moving if we've gone too far
        if( rope.y > 600.0 )
        {
            rope.y = 600.0;
            ropeMove = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rope = MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc.fishyrope_mc.hitbox_mc;
var ropeMove:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ropeCode);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onSpacebarUp);

function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
        ropeMove = !ropeMove; // toggles ropeMove (i.e. if it's true, sets it to false, and vice versa)
}

function ropeCode(e:Event):void
{
    // move the rope
    if( ropeMove )
    {
        rope.y += xSpeed;

        // stop moving if we've gone too far
        if( rope.y > 600.0 )
        {
            rope.y = 600.0;
            ropeMove = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var ropemove:Boolean = true;
var xSpeed = 5;
var once:Boolean=false;


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ropeCode);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,onSpacebarUp);
function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        if (ropemove==true)
        {
            if(once==false)
            {
                ropemove = false;
                once=true
            }
        }
        if(ropemove==false)
        {
            ropemove==true
        }

    }
    if (rope.x >= stage.stageWidth )
    {
        ropemove = false;
    }
    trace(ropemove)

}
function ropeCode(e:Event):void
{

    if (ropemove == true)
    {
        rope.x +=  xSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi bennettliam , thanks so much for your help , I really appreciate it. If you check my post you will see i have edited my code based on what you have said. However now a strange thing is happening. The movieclip starts moving on its own when the movie loads and if I space bar , then it stops :/ . What noobness am I doing? thanks

Comment: at a quick glance, it might be because ropemove is true at the start

Comment: ok edited my code again now its works, as in it drops down but doesnt stop after reaching a point. So i did a trace of the x and y both ..even when the objects are moving the Y does not change. Hence they dont stop. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I can spot in your code:

1.) Everything is inside your Event.ENTER_FRAME event handler. This means every frame, that code is going to be run: including where you're adding a keyboard event listener. After 1 second, (assuming you are running at 30 fps) onSpacebarUp() will fire 30 times when you press space, and keeps increasing. Probably not a good idea, pretty sure you only want to add this once.

2.) The part where the boolean value will cause your movieclip to move is in a method: dropRope(). But this is not called anywhere, so it is actually not doing anything. Also may not need the event argument (the `e:event`) part, as you're not using it nor is it being called from an event.

BennettLiam's code should do something closer to what you want, I'm just adding this answer as an explanation for why your code isn't working. In their answer, they've fixed the above problems I mentioned: moved the event listener code for the keyboard outside of the event frame handler loop so it is only added once, and changed the enter frame event handler to call dropRope() o every frame, so that it is doing something.

Comment: Actually, it DOES exist in AS3. But it's not an elegant way to refer to the main class.

Comment: oh you're right. 'root' does exist. Removed it from my post.

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation , i really appreciate it. There is no point simply picking up codes from people if I cant understand it .